# TypeScript 2.3.1 breaking changes in SystemJS plunk

Tags: typescript, systemjs

Here is [official Angular + TypeScript plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/wfzJaYrJknubeW0ZmWgL?p=preview) that uses SystemJS 0.19.31 and has been changed to use TypeScript 2.3.0.

When SystemJS configuration of the same plunk [is changed to TypeScript 2.3.1 or 2.3.2](https://plnkr.co/edit/qSnW4OZzybCA9yA7AIe4?p=preview)

```
'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.3.1/lib/typescript.js'
```

it just stops working. No errors in console.

What is the problem with TypeScript 2.3.1? Is it a known issue? Is the problem specific to current setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with SystemJS module format auto detection.

It has this regex to check if the source is es6 and needs to be transpiled:

```
  // good enough ES6 module detection regex - format detections not designed to be accurate, but to handle the 99% use case
  var esmRegEx = /(^\s*|[}\);\n]\s*)(import\s*(['"]|(\*\s+as\s+)?[^"'\(\)\n;]+\s*from\s*['"]|\{)|export\s+\*\s+from\s+["']|export\s*(\{|default|function|class|var|const|let|async\s+function))/;
```

Sure enough, TypeScript 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 have this comment in the source code which matches that regex:

```
  // For an export of a module, we may be in a declaration file, and it may be accessed elsewhere. E.g.:
  //     declare module "a" { export type T = number; }
  //     declare module "b" { import { T } from "a"; export const x: T; }
```

So, when debugging this, you can see that SystemJS loads a transpiler (typescript), determines that it's es6 and needs to be transpiled, loads a transpiler, ..., and never comes to transpiling your code (`main.ts`)

The proper format for typescript is 'global', so adding this to SystemJS config at the top level should fix it:

```
  meta: {typescript: {format: 'global'}}
```